# xelatex -Undefined control sequence

Tags: xetex, errors

So I am trying to work with this tex file for CV available at http://kjhealy.github.com/kjh-vita/

The only thing I change is the font from pragmata to consolas. 2 problems I get a pdf output, with a tiny "on" at the end of the page plus 12 errors all with the same description in the output:

```
xelatex! Undefined control sequence
```

OK so let's decribe the errors in detail(as you might see them upon compiling the above file).

```
1.Pointer at \ind command in the code---error in output window is the following
xelatex>! undefined control sequence.
xelatex><argument>\scriptsize \VCRevision
xelatex>                       \ on \VCDateTEX
xelatex>l.265 \ind
xelatex>       Kieran Healy.1999.``href{http://www.k........
```

Could anyone also please let me know how to copy-paste the error details from the output window?

Comment: Please quote the whole error. "xelatex! Undefined control sequence" is not enough information to know what's wrong. Also, you do not need to sign your posts, since they are automatically signed. Finally, you can display code by indenting lines with 4 spaces.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: As a note, is there a reason why you want to use this CV layout in particular? I can't see a single PDF showing how it looks, and there's already great and easy CV layouts such as `moderncv` working out of the box in TeXLive.

Comment: Thanks both, I'll use moderncv and see if it works out.Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is caused by this line:

```
\rfoot{\texttt{\scriptsize \VCRevision\ on \VCDateTEX}}
```

`\VCRevision` and `\VCDateTEX` belong to the [`vc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/vc) package which is for version control. Simply comment out this `\rfoot` line, or install and use the `vc` package, use it with

```
\input{vc}
```

in your preamble.

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora: nice to see that it helped! Perhaps consider upvoting and accepting the answer then. ;-)

Comment: Hm, this is my Vita template. So now I am actively causing problems in the world of tex/latex on stack exchange. I suppose this is progress of a sort.

As Stefan says, the error is happening because you're not using the `vc` package. I think I put a note in the template pointing this out.

Comment: @Kieran: there's no no problem, it just caused a question. Even this would not have been necessary if the OP would have read your comments in the file, especially regarding \rfoot.